# Blob storage connection data flow through WAF

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-gateway

We are using the blob storage connection string within the application to upload the data, using this method that the data also flows through the Azure WAF? All the web apps are behind the gateway/WAF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Web App is uploading data to Storage Blob then it is a outbound traffic which will not flow via Application Gateway. Only Incoming traffic to Web App can be passed via Application Gateway.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks, Does it a recommended to transfer the data to the blob without routing to application gateway/WAF?

Comment: The data from Web App to Storage account will be transferred by Azure Backbone. It is completely safe to transfer data directly and you don't need a WAF in this case.

Comment: In my case, data is in on-prem and web app will transfer data to blob based on the storage connection string supplied. is it still recommended practice or there should be a specific app that will transfer data to blob via WAF?

Comment: How is the data from On-Premises transferred? Via public Internet ? 
I don't think so you need a WAF to inspect the data that is transferred from On-Premises. You can send  data directly to Storage account as it is secured.

Comment: There is a desktop application that is running on-prem and the application uses blob connection string directly to transfer the data.

Comment: Since the data transfer happen over HTTPS, I don't think you need a WAF in between.

Comment: Thanks, there is no VPN. Even its via HTTPS but still on the public internet. Not sure, should go for VPN or not?

Comment: Your Storage Account has Public endpoint. You need to enable Service Endpoints if you are using VPN gateway. Again, you can restrict who can access the Storage account with IP address. That will be useful for your case as only your On-Prem is accessing your Storage account via Public Internet, so you can lock down the IP to allow access and block the rest.